# How to output the Double with 20 decimal places?

Tags: java, double, wrapper

Hello to all,

```
Double d = 1.000000000000000000000000000000001;
        System.out.println(d);
```

The code above prints 1.0 but i want d to store entire value.
desired output was 1.000000000000000000000000000000001

my concern is how to store this value in double?
is there any way to increase the decimals a double can store?
please guide me

Comment: `double` only has 15-16 digits of precision so you cannot store such a number.  Do you have a real use case for this is it just theoretical?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Example:

```
BigDecimal test = new BigDecimal("1.000000000000000000000000000000001");
System.out.println(test);
```

The reason that the same cannot be represented using a `double` is that `double` has 64 bits.

Comment: err. it prints `1`. Should be in quotes.

Comment: but is there any way to do it with double?

Comment: @JackAss: No. This is a basic restriction: there are an infinite number of real values. And there are only 64 bits in a double. So obviously, all the numbers can't be represented as doubles.

Comment: @JBNizet edit the answer and add this comment as well please. :-)

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

as per above link double has 53 decimal bits of 64 in total, in which 16 decimal places can be stored

Answer (score 0):

You can have the double, and another one, and multiply the main double by the amount of decimal places in itself, then add the other double to the new number divide it by the decimal places wanted and then print that

```
Double b = 1.000000000000000
Double ab = 0.00001
System.out.println (b × 1000000000000000 + ab × 100000 ÷ 100000000000000000000)
```

I might have done the math wrong but that's the idea.